# Laravel - Admin section generator [Laravel 5.4]

Tags: php, laravel, crud, grocery-crud, crud-admin-generator

I have been developing a web site that is kind of an online store and my user needs to access to control the products, stock and other things like that and having a basic CRUD of some of my Models, so I want to install something like `GroceryCRUD` (called `ImageCRUD` for Laravel), but the versión in its documentaion needs Laravel 4.2 and I am developing with the most recent version of it (5.4).

In few words, my question is... Is there something like `GroceryCRUD` for Laravel in this version?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some package that you can install for example :

Read this for more information

https://laravel-news.com/13-laravel-admin-panel-generators

Comment: Thank you so much, very useful and simple